# Importing a module::class and referring to it by its short name

Tags: raku

When I export a class in Perl 6, I want to refer to it using its name only without having to specify its module:

```
> use MyLibrary::User;
> User
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling <unknown file>
Undeclared name:
    User used at line 1

> MyLibrary::User;
```

What's the way to get of calling it by its full name `MyLibrary::User;` and be able to call it as `User`?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it very easily like this:

```
constant User = MyLibrary::User;
```